# Image not served inside jsp from Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, stream, blob

I have a jsp wherein for each row of the table i need to display the image present in the database. I retrieve all the table row data from database including image as Blob and store it in a bean. The image is stored in the bean as byte array like this:

```
photo = rs.getBlob("PHOTO");
photoByteArray = photo.getBytes(1, (int)photo.length());
```

While looping over the list of beans in jsp, the src attribute points to a servlet like this:

```
<img class="img" width="55" height="50" src="displayThumbnail?photoData=${part.photoData}">
```

which serves the image like shown below but they don't show up however upon debugging the byte array do seem to have data.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
    String photoDataStr = request.getParameter("photoData");
    byte[] photoData = null;
    if(photoDataStr != null) {
        photoData = photoDataStr.getBytes();
    }
    o.write(photoData);
    o.close();
}
```

However the image doesn't show up. Now, if i query the database for each individual image as shown below, the images do show up fine in that case.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
            try {
        if(conn == null) {
            conn = open();
        }
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select photo from PART_PHOTOS where id = ?");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        pstmt.setString(1, id);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            Blob b = rs.getBlob("photo");
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            response.setContentLength((int) b.length());
            InputStream is = b.getBinaryStream();
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            byte buf[] = new byte[(int) b.length()];
            is.read(buf);
            os.write(buf);
            os.close();
            is.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            rs = null;
        }
        if (pstmt != null) {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pstmt = null;
        }
        //check if it's the end of the loop
            if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    conn = null;
                }
    }
}
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone can provide any recommendations around the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that you can put random binary data into an HTML file, and it will be parsed correctly, and sent back to your server intact. This is a bad assumption! If nothing else, the byte that corresponds to the ASCII for the quote character is going to cause problems, right? Not to mention encoding issues, and the fact that the parameters to a URL must be urlencoded. This is just doomed to fail.

To make this work, you'd have to have some kind of explicit text encoding of the binary data when you serve the page (base64, maybe), and then decode the servlet parameter back to binary image data after the URL is posted back.

Comment: @BaluC : Is there any quick way out of this without spending too much time on setting up cache etc.

Comment: @BalusC: as you should now be able to see from some other comments left by the OP, he was, indeed, trying to stick the image data directly into the HTML: quote, "The ${part.photoData} returns the byte array which is retrieved from the initial database call.". Then he expects his servlet to be able to extract that byte array from where he embedded it as the URL in the <img> tag, and return it directly back to the requestor. I thought I was pretty clear on my explanation, but none of the other responses seem to have appreciated what's going on.

Comment: Oh he attempted to pass the whole image as parameter! Sorry, I see it now. I interpreted it as an image identifier. I take my words back.

Answer (score 0):

Your first processRequest() snippet is only sending back the byte representation of the photoData request parameter and not the photo data identified by the parameter.  Looks like a bug in your code.

It seems you are trying to solve your problem in the wrong manner.  When you first create the HTML table, storing the image in your "bean" from your first query gives you nothing unless you cache the data, and the subseqent displayThumbnail request retrieves the image from the cache, avoiding the database query.

If you do not want to mess with caching, then there is no need to store the image in your initial bean since it gives you nothing, and just do something like your second processRequest() snippet to fetch the image directly when the browser asks for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `${part.photoData}` expression must return some ID. In the processRequest() method you must get that ID value (by using request.getParameter("photoData")) and by that value retrieve image from database (or better from cache or from file system) and send the binary data to web client.

Comment: The ${part.photoData} returns the byte array which is retrieved from the initial database call. I don't want to make separate database calls for retrieving images.

Comment: you can not put byte array into src attribute of img tag,, it'll not work.
And if you don't want to make call to database you could keep map which has the ID as key and byte array as value.